# Continuous Time Markov Chain Transition Probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> Consider a continuous time Markov chain with state space {1, 2, 3} and transition rates $$q(1,2) = 2, q(1, 3) = 3$$ $$q(2, 1) = 0, q(2, 3) = 5 $$ $$ q(3, 1) = 1, q(3, 2) = 0$$ Calculate $P(X_{7.5} = 2 | X_0 = 1)$.

We haven't yet discussed these types of conditional probabilities in class, and our textbook doesn't do a great job of explaining the method in which we should calculate them. All I can find at the moment is the following lemma: $$P(X_{s+t} = j | X_s = i) = \frac{\pi(j) p_{t}(j, i)}{\pi(i)}$$ Thus, in this case, the answer would simply be $$P(X_{7.5} = 2 | X_0 = 1) = \frac{\pi(2) p_{7.5}(2, 1)}{\pi(1)}$$ I can easily find this stationary distribution, but I'm not sure how to think about $p_{7.5}(2,1)$. I believe we can find an imbedded discrete time markov chain for this process, but I'm still not sure how we would find $p_{7.5}(2, 1)$.

Any push in the right direction is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you are studying Markov chains before becoming familiar with the concept of conditional probability? That is odd... anyway, the transition probabilities are given by $P(X_t=j|X_0=i)=P_{ij}(t)$ which are the entries of the matrix $P(t)=e^{tQ}$. Do you know how to compute this matrix?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 no, sorry, I didn't explain very well. I'm very comfortable with the concept of conditional probabilities as they relate to discrete time markov chains. We had not yet covered these explicit calculations as they relate to *continuous* time chains, however.

I'm not sure how to calculate this by hand, but I'm able to do the calculation with wolfram alpha's help. This is simply the exponential of the matrix of transition rates, $Q$, multiplied by $t$, no?